# Django ModelMultipleChoiceFilter - not_in method

Tags: python, django, filter, static-methods

I'm trying to set up a ModelMultipleChoiceFilter in Django, and am wondering if I'm able to pass in a method to it. The filter is meant to exclude any param values for my delivery status field, so I wanted to set up a static method which would exclude the values from the queryset.

I initially set up a CharFilter, but params is converting the comma in the URL to be %2c. For example, I would pass in two statuses (PENDING,STARTED), and the url would end up looking like: /?status_not_in=PENDING%2cSTARTED.

So I'm trying to get the URL to be /?status_not_in=PENDING&status_not_in=STARTED. This is what I have set up so far for the filter:

```
status_not_in = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    field_name='delivery_status__status',
    method='get_delivery_status_not_in_new',
    lookup_expr='iexact',
    queryset=Delivery.objects.all(),
    label='Filter for statuses not in: PENDING, STARTED, COMPLETED, ERRORS, EXPIRED',
    conjoined=False,
)
```

and this is the method I want to use:

```
@staticmethod
def get_delivery_status_not_in(queryset, name, value):
    trimmed_value_list = [status.upper().strip() for status in value]
    qs = queryset.exclude(delivery_status__status__in=trimmed_value_list)
    return qs
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.